# Perform calculation on part of a query then add it to total of query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the total of the result of part of a query then use it in the rest of the query, so the results of the 3 blocks of code need to be added together and multiplied by either 2 or 1.5 then that figure added to the total which will be added to the `FScore` column.

I've written the part I don't know how to do in plain text:

```
DECLARE @PERC90 float = 0.9
DECLARE @PERC80 float = 0.8
DECLARE @PERC70 float = 0.7
DECLARE @PERC60 float = 0.6
DECLARE @PERC50 float = 0.5
DECLARE @PERC40 float = 0.4
DECLARE @PERC30 float = 0.3
DECLARE @PERC20 float = 0.2
DECLARE @PERC0 float = 0.1

UPDATE Results SET FScore = 
  ((IIF(L1percentile >= 90, @PERC90,
   IIF(L1percentile >= 80, @PERC80,
   IIF(L1percentile >= 70, @PERC70,
   IIF(L1percentile >= 60, @PERC60,
   IIF(L1percentile >= 50, @PERC50,
   IIF(L1percentile >= 40, @PERC40,
   IIF(L1percentile >= 30, @PERC30,
   IIF(L1percentile >= 20, @PERC20, @PERC0))))))))) * 
   IIF(L1score <= 50, 1, 1.25))
   +
   ((IIF(L2percentile >= 90, @PERC90,
   IIF(L2percentile >= 80, @PERC80,
   IIF(L2percentile >= 70, @PERC70,
   IIF(L2percentile >= 60, @PERC60,
   IIF(L2percentile >= 50, @PERC50,
   IIF(L2percentile >= 40, @PERC40,
   IIF(L2percentile >= 30, @PERC30,
   IIF(L2percentile >= 20, @PERC20, @PERC0))))))))) * 
   IIF(L2score <= 50, 1, 1.25))
   +
   ((IIF(L3percentile >= 90, @PERC90,
   IIF(L3percentile >= 80, @PERC80,
   IIF(L3percentile >= 70, @PERC70,
   IIF(L3percentile >= 60, @PERC60,
   IIF(L3percentile >= 50, @PERC50,
   IIF(L3percentile >= 40, @PERC40,
   IIF(L3percentile >= 30, @PERC30,
   IIF(L3percentile >= 20, @PERC20, @PERC0))))))))) * 
   IIF(L3score <= 50, 1, 1.25))
   +
   (If Results.totalscores = 1 then Add the total of the 3 scores above together and multiply by 2, 
 else mutiply by 1.5)

FROM Results
WHERE testdate >= '2020-03-12'
```

Comment: You can wrap the inner query in another query, and do your final sum in the outer query.

Comment: For the final step, do you always sum the 3 scores and then multiple by either 2 or 1.5? (Also, instead of the nested IIFs, use case statements.)

Comment: @user2096512 . . .  Why are you nesting `IIF()` ten levels deep instead of using `CASE`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Because I'm an SQL novice, having seen the example I will change it to using CASE instead, much nicer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way, using a Common Table Expression. I replaced the IIFs with case statements (easier to read/debug), and assumed that the three calculations are always summed before the final multiplication.

```
WITH cteSum
 as (select
       ResultsId  --  Or whatever the primary Key for table Results is
      ,(case
          when L1percentile >= 90 then @PERC90
          when L1percentile >= 80 then @PERC90
          when L1percentile >= 70 then @PERC90
          when L1percentile >= 60 then @PERC90
          when L1percentile >= 50 then @PERC90
          when L1percentile >= 40 then @PERC90
          when L1percentile >= 30 then @PERC90
          when L1percentile >= 20 then @PERC90
          else @PERC0
        end * IIF(L1score <= 50, 1, 1.25))
       + (case
            when L2percentile >= 90 then @PERC90
            when L2percentile >= 80 then @PERC90
            when L2percentile >= 70 then @PERC90
            when L2percentile >= 60 then @PERC90
            when L2percentile >= 50 then @PERC90
            when L2percentile >= 40 then @PERC90
            when L2percentile >= 30 then @PERC90
            when L2percentile >= 20 then @PERC90
            else @PERC0
          end * IIF(L2score <= 50, 1, 1.25))
       + (case
            when L3percentile >= 90 then @PERC90
            when L3percentile >= 80 then @PERC90
            when L3percentile >= 70 then @PERC90
            when L3percentile >= 60 then @PERC90
            when L3percentile >= 50 then @PERC90
            when L3percentile >= 40 then @PERC90
            when L3percentile >= 30 then @PERC90
            when L3percentile >= 20 then @PERC90
            else @PERC0
          end * IIF(L3score <= 50, 1, 1.25))  CalcedSum
      from Results
      where testdate >= '2020-03-12'
    )
UPDATE Results
 set FScore = CalcedSum * case re.totalscores
                            when 1 then 2
                            else 1.5
                          end
 from Results  re
  inner join cteSum  cte
   on cte.ResultsId = re.ResultsId  --  Use PK to only update the desired rows
```

Check it over, I was not able to run/debug it, but the syntax should be good.

(It'd be nice to lose all those @PERC variables, but I don't think there's a simple way to do that.)

Comment: Thanks Philip, that looks good but I get the following error though: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.

Comment: It's ok I fixed it, needed to add a semi-colon in front of the WITH.

Comment: I always start writing CTEs like so `;WITH`. The downside is, this tends to start religious wars--some folks are very touchy when it comes to semicolons, and for that reason I left it off here.

Comment: Ha, I can imagine, well in my very limited experience it doesn't work without it so I'm in the semi-colon camp.

Comment: The argument is: end every statement with a semicolon, because some day Real Soon Now Microsoft will release a version of SQL Server that requires ending *all* statements with a semicolon, as per the .Net languages.